# Required any one field validation in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want any one of the text field necessary either email id or phone no.
what code should i write if that field should me inside a grid item.

Comment: *'...what code should i write'* without seeing what you have written so far, it is hard to say

Comment: Hi thanks for submitting your question. Before answering it, we would like to know what you have tried until now and any errors you've faced

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional rendering to email if phone is invalid and render phone textfield if email is invalid.

```
const App = () => {
    const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);
    const [isPhoneValid, setIsPhoneValid] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");

    return (
        <div>
            { isPhoneValid ? null : (
                <input 
                    type="email" 
                    placeholder="Enter Email" 
                    onChange={event => {
                                        setIsEmailValid(true)
                                        setEmail(event.target.value)
                                      }
                              }
             ) }
             { isEmailValid ? null : (
                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Enter number" 
                    onChange={event => {
                                        setIsPhoneValid(true)
                                        setPhone(event.target.value)
                                      }
                              }
             ) }
        </div>
    );
}
```